# Passing custom type as parameter from PL to BLL to DAL to Insert record?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parameters, crud

I am using Entity framworke in my project. I am using 3 layer architecture ( Presentation layer(PL), Business logic layer(BLL) and Data Access Layer(BAL)). Entity framework define all entity as well as CRUD operation to BD.

I have encountered one basic problem. Suppose i need to Insert customer in DB. I want to
do is as follow

```
---------------PL-------------
Customer ObjCustomer=new Customer();

//init object
ObjCustomer.Name="";
--------------
------------

BLL.InsertCustomer(ObjCustomer)

------------------------------------------------

-------------------BLL---------------

DAL.InsertCustomer(ObjCustomer)

------------------------------------

-------------------DAL---------------

CustomerReporitory.InsertCustomer(ObjCustomer)

------------------------------------
```

Now problem is that **customer** is defined in DAL as part of EF. It is not advisable to take DAL ref in PL. I want to pass custom class type like customer as parameter. How to do that. Please me some sample code.

Comment: Does Customer have any methods or is it just a bunch of properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Customer in your presentation layer shouldn't be the Customer from your business or data layer. The Customer in your presentation layer should be something similar to a ViewModel, so it should only carry attributes and be declared in the business layer. That is the type of object that should be sent to the business layer for CreateCustomer, which in turn creates a business entity or DAO from it and passes it for persistence.

### Presentation layer

```
UserViewModel theUser=new UserViewModel(userNameField,passwordField);
userController.CreateUser(theUser);
```

### Business layer

```
public class UserController
{
    public void CreateUser(UserViewModel user)
    {
        bool isUserValid=ValidateUser(user);
        if(isUserValid)
        {
            UserEntity theEntity=new UserEntity(user);
            _userRepository.Create(theEntity);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidUserException("This user isn't valid");
        }
    }
}
```

### Data layer

```
public class UserRepository
{
    public void Create(UserEntity user)
    {
        /* store user to database or whatever */
    }
}
```

Comment: If Customer entity is defined in BLL it will be accessible from PL but not from DAL. so from BLL to DAL i have to pass all customer attribute as separate parameter? Can you please show me example code>

Comment: In the BLL you need to create an entity from the ViewModel according to your business rules and pass it to the DAL for persistence, yes.

Comment: Generally we take reference of DAL in BLL BUT NOT REVERSE. so if i define entity in BLL how it will be accessible in DAL?

Comment: That's one of the shortcomings in a regular 3-tier architecture; the entity has to be defined in the DAL, or you'll have to use a Data Access Object defined in the DAL that you construct from your entity.

Comment: Thank a lot for your explanation/sample code. Now i have confusion only at this line [UserEntity theEntity=new UserEntity(user);]. How do i create a **UserEntity** from [UserViewModel] type OR You mean to say construct a object of UserEntity from [user] object pass from PL and finally pass it to the persistence layer.

Comment: Exactly. You may not be able to do it in the ctor ofc, i kind of shorthanded it.

Answer (score 0):

If your model has no methods or functionality and is just a set of get/set properties you can place it in a separate assembly/namespace and have all the layers take the model as a dependency.  This is only recommended in very simple applications though and for anything more complex use Tobias's approach.